# In Django admin, how can I increase the width of the ManyToMany field's widget when using filter_horizontal?

Tags: django, django-admin

In Django admin, how can I increase the width of the ManyToMany field's widget when using filter_horizontal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could apply custom classes to the fields using [ModelAdmin Fieldsets](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets) you wanted to change and add an extra stylesheet with:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        css = {
            "all": ("my_styles.css",)
        }
```

Otherwise you'll have to write your own admin templates or widgets.